# Как правильно организовать многопроцессное приложение в Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, процесс, multiprocessing, распараллеливание

Исходный код имеет следующий вид:

```
const listener = new Listener();

listener.start();

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  listener.stop();
});
```

Нужно разделить `Listener` на два таким образом, чтобы вынести аналогичную конструкцию в дочерний процесс (чтобы разделить нагрузку между ядрами процессора, например).

Как правильно это сделать средствами Node.js?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238762/how-to-organize-a-multiprocess-application-in-node-js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Разнородные дочерние процессы**

Насколько я понял, обработчики дочерних процессов нужно обязательно выносить в отдельные файлы, и другого решения Node.js на сегодняшний день не предлагает:

***./index.js***

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const processHandlers = [
  './subprocess/process1.js',
  './subprocess/process2.js',
];

const processes = processHandlers.map((h) => fork(h, []));

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  processes.forEach((process) => process.send('stop'));
});
```

***./subprocess/process1.js***

```
const listener = new Listener1();    
listener.start();

process.on('message', (m) => {
  if (m === 'stop') {
    listener.stop();
    process.disconnect();
  }
});
```

***./subprocess/process2.js***

```
const listener = new Listener2();
listener.start();

process.on('message', (m) => {
  if (m === 'stop') {
    listener.stop();
    process.disconnect();
  }
});
```

---

**2. Однородные дочерние процессы**

В случае, если потомки — однородные конкурирующие вычислительные единицы, можно использовать модуль [сluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html):

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Обработчик ведущего процесса

  // Запуск дочерних процессов
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {
  // Обработчик дочерних процессов
  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

Comment: Я когда игрался с Node посылал функции в дочерние процессы, вполне сносно работало, хотя на счёт КПД этого способа конечно не могу сказать ничего, исходников к сожалению не сохранилось